# An image does not exist locally with the tag

Tags: codeship

I'm playing with codeship.

When codeship try to push the docker image to my private registry i have the error:

```
Build Error: Image Push error for image myprivateregistry.com/sancho/test:latest, An image does not exist locally with the tag: myprivateregistry.com/sancho/test


2017-09-11T20:08:44.814Z test build/pull started
2017-09-11T20:09:23.019Z test build/pull finished successfully
2017-09-11T20:09:23.019Z test build/push started for test
2017-09-11T20:09:23.156Z test The push refers to a repository [myprivateregistry.com/sancho/test]
```

my codeship-steps.yml

```
- service: test
  type: push
  image_name: myprivateregistry.com/sancho/test
  registry: https://myprivateregistry.com
  encrypted_dockercfg_path: dockercfg.encrypted
```

Do you see any error in my configruation ?

Answer (score 1):

I add

```
image_tag: latest
```

And it work !